# How to save elements in array in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

i have this web source

```
<div id="Family">
   <div class="Male">
      <div id="m-1234" class="boy">
      <div id="m-5678" class="boy">
      <div id="m-9012" class="boy">
</div>
```

I want to save id starts with 'm-' in array and want to click on these elements in loop using selenium IDE.
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using while to address 'm-' part

[image]

should work :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't address the m part but the following will store the id's and may help:

```
storeAttribute //div[@id='Family']/div[@class='Male']/div[@class='boy'][1]@id var1
```

As in:

[image]